# Escape character for " in ValidationExpression in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am using regular expression to filter the invalid input entered by the end user.

The acceptable input is `word`, `space`, `digital` and `.` `/` `@` `,` `#` `&` `$` `_` `:` `?` `'` `%` `!` `–` `~` `"` `|` `+` `;` `”` `{` `}` `-` `\`.
Below is my code.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgVEditTB1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEditTB1"   
     ValidationExpression="^[\w\s\d\-\.\/\@\,\#\&\$\:\?\"\'\%\!\–\~\|\+\;\”\{\}\-\\]+$"   ErrorMessage="Invalid Special Character"  />
```

However, I am encountering problem to escape `"` in the `ValidataionExpression`, it errors out with

> Server Tag is not well formed error.

I tried to change the escape character to:

```
\""  
\"   
""
```

It also gives me the same error.

What should be the correct escape character to put in the `ValidationExpression`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to pass in the HTML encoding values. So, passing `&quot;` would be like passing `"`. Something like this: `ValidationExpression="^[^&quot;]+$"`. In this regex I am saying: Match any character from the beginning till the end of the string which is not a quotation mark (`"`).

The same applies to the other special symbols. You can take a look [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for more encoding values.